# ProgressDialog does not want to update the message

Tags: android, progressdialog

I just tried to implement a progressdialog and I have some issues to change the text during my long and complex calculations.

```
for (String aString:myStringArray){
    Log.v(TAG, aString);
    mProgressDialog.incrementProgressBy(1);
    mProgressDialog.setMessage(aString);
}
```

I can clearly see the incrementProgressBy working and my dialog updating, but the message does not change.

Any idea on how to make that work?

Thank a lot.

Answer (score 60, accepted):

Just found the answer, that's working fine:

```
runOnUiThread(changeMessage);
```

with that code:

```
private Runnable changeMessage = new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        //Log.v(TAG, strCharacters);
        m_ProgressDialog.setMessage(strCharacters);
    }
};
```

Comment: this does not work. i try to update the message from the UI Thread but it does not change.

Comment: Yeah, this is so easy to help with "this is not working" as message :-p

Comment: @Waza_Be Sorry for being so direct :D Actually I tried your code to update the message of `ProgressDialog` but the `ProgressDialog` just hangs with older message in it. I am trying to update the message from `doInBackground()` of `AsyncTask`. Any idea how to do it?

Comment: This is for you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6450275/android-how-to-work-with-asynctasks-progressdialog

Comment: Comment on your original answer : this was exactly what I was doing while having the refresh problem. In my case, it was because a message was not set before showing the dialog, and could not be added after. By putting an initial message with the same code, updating it later on it works fine.

Comment: @JMLord Thanks, I think you should add it as an answer, it solved my problem!

Comment: @JMLord Yeah, thanks for pointing that out. Another annoying Android API bug that will probably never get fixed.

Comment: @ JM Lord  Thanks it was the issue.

Answer (score 0):

I upload pictures to `Firebase` in a loop and updating the `ProgressDialog` each image:

(I am in a `Fragment`, so I use `getActivity()` before calling to `runOnUiThread()`)

```
List<Bitmap> bitmaps;
int picCounter = 1;
...

progressDialog = ProgressDialog.show
 (getContext(), "sending...", "just a minute", false, false);

new Thread(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        for (int i = 0; i < bitmaps.size(); i++) {

            String filename = String.valueOf(i);

            uploadPic(bitmaps.get(i), "img" + filename, new MyCallback() {
                @Override
                public void onFinish() {
                    picCounter++;
                    Objects.requireNonNull(getActivity()).runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                        public void run() {
                            progressDialog.setTitle ("upoading " + picCounter + "image from " + bitmaps.size());
                        }
                    });
                }
            });
        }
   }
}).start();
```

uploadPic method:

```
public interface MyCallback { void onFinish ();}

private void uploadPic(final Bitmap bitmap, final String fileName, final MyCallback callback) {
   ... // uploading to firebase and then:
   callback.onFinish();
}
```