# Changing Progress Dialog Message While Running

Tags: android, dialog, message, progress

I've got a fairly simple issue I'm not sure how to resolve. I want to change the message text of a Progress Dialog while it's running and showing. An example of this would be something like a "time remaining" counter that would count down while the progress animation is spinning. I'm not sure how I would approach this because doing progressDialog.setMessage(String), even within a running thread, will not change anything in the Dialog itself. Thank you!

Comment: possible duplicate of [ProgressDialog does not want to update the message](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3947080/progressdialog-does-not-want-to-update-the-message)

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You might want to check [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3947080/progressdialog-does-not-want-to-update-the-message) out.

In short: You need to create a little Runnable which you can execute on the UI thread using `runOnUiThread`...