# android how to work with asynctasks progressdialog

Tags: android

Asynctask have 4 override methods `onPreExecute()`, `doInBackground()`, `onProgressUpdate()`, `onPostExecute()`
except `onProgressUpdate` all are working.
What should I do so that onProgressUpdate() should work.
Can anybody please briefly explain me what's the use of `onProgressUpdate()`, what should write within this?

Comment: `progressDialog.setIndeterminate(false);` if you have given `true`

Answer (score 65, accepted):

`onProgressUpdate()` is used to operate progress of asynchronous operations via this method. Note the param with datatype `Integer`. This corresponds to the second parameter in the class definition. This callback can be triggered from within the body of the `doInBackground()` method by calling `publishProgress()`.

### Example

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class AsyncTaskExample extends Activity {

    protected TextView _percentField;

    protected Button _cancelButton;

    protected InitTask _initTask;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        _percentField = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.percent_field);
        _cancelButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.cancel_button);
        _cancelButton.setOnClickListener(new CancelButtonListener());
        _initTask = new InitTask();
        _initTask.execute(this);
    }

    protected class CancelButtonListener implements View.OnClickListener {

        public void onClick(View v) {
            _initTask.cancel(true);
        }
    }

    /**
     * sub-class of AsyncTask
     */
    protected class InitTask extends AsyncTask<Context, Integer, String> {

        // -- run intensive processes here
        // -- notice that the datatype of the first param in the class definition matches the param passed to this
        // method
        // -- and that the datatype of the last param in the class definition matches the return type of this method
        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(Context... params) {
            // -- on every iteration
            // -- runs a while loop that causes the thread to sleep for 50 milliseconds
            // -- publishes the progress - calls the onProgressUpdate handler defined below
            // -- and increments the counter variable i by one
            int i = 0;
            while (i <= 50) {
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(50);
                    publishProgress(i);
                    i++;
                }
                catch (Exception e) {
                    Log.i("makemachine", e.getMessage());
                }
            }
            return "COMPLETE!";
        }

        // -- gets called just before thread begins
        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            Log.i("makemachine", "onPreExecute()");
            super.onPreExecute();
        }

        // -- called from the publish progress
        // -- notice that the datatype of the second param gets passed to this method
        @Override
        protected void onProgressUpdate(Integer... values) {
            super.onProgressUpdate(values);
            Log.i("makemachine", "onProgressUpdate(): " + String.valueOf(values[0]));
            _percentField.setText((values[0] * 2) + "%");
            _percentField.setTextSize(values[0]);
        }

        // -- called if the cancel button is pressed
        @Override
        protected void onCancelled() {
            super.onCancelled();
            Log.i("makemachine", "onCancelled()");
            _percentField.setText("Cancelled!");
            _percentField.setTextColor(0xFFFF0000);
        }

        // -- called as soon as doInBackground method completes
        // -- notice that the third param gets passed to this method
        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
            super.onPostExecute(result);
            Log.i("makemachine", "onPostExecute(): " + result);
            _percentField.setText(result);
            _percentField.setTextColor(0xFF69adea);
            _cancelButton.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I wanna for spaecific time the dilog should appear. If takes more time I want give an alert.then where i will give that?

Comment: In onProgressUpdate(), super method not accepting Integer value as argument. It accepts only Void

Answer (score 4):

[onProgressUpdate](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html#onProgressUpdate%28Progress...%29) runs on the UI thread after [publishProgress](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html#publishProgress%28Progress...%29) is invoked. From AsyncTask documentation - your code should look something like this

```
private class DownloadFilesTask extends AsyncTask<URL, Integer, Long> {
    protected Long doInBackground(URL... urls) {
        int count = urls.length;
        long totalSize = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
            totalSize += Downloader.downloadFile(urls[i]);
            publishProgress((int) ((i / (float) count) * 100));
        }
        return totalSize;
    }

    protected void onProgressUpdate(Integer... progress) {
        setProgressPercent(progress[0]);
    }

    protected void onPostExecute(Long result) {
        showDialog("Downloaded " + result + " bytes");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
hey this might help you??
```

the progress bar will automatically disappear when you will get the response

```
User_AsyncTaskk extends AsyncTask
 public class User_AsyncTask extends AsyncTask<String, String, String>
    {
        String response = "";

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute()
        {
            try
            {
                if (progressDialog != null)
                    progressDialog.cancel();
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {

            }
            progressDialog = ProgressDialog.show(DisplayDetails.this, "", "Please wait...", true, true);
            progressDialog.setCancelable(false);
            progressDialog.show();
        }


 protected String doInBackground(String... params)
        {

            try
            {


               //Complete ur Code

                Log.i("AUTO ", "response  is : " + response);
                return response;
            }

            catch (Exception e)
            {

            }
        }

 @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String s)
        {
            if (progressDialog != null) {
                progressDialog.dismiss();
                progressDialog = null;
            }

            try {



            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {

            }
        }
```