# Progress dialog doesn't update on an AsyncTask onProgressUpdate

Tags: android, multithreading, dialog, ui-thread

I'm developing an Android 3.1 and above application.

I have this code to download some json data:

```
public class FormsListActivity extends ListActivity
{
    private List<Form> mForms;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
      super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
      setContentView(R.layout.formlist);

      FormListAsyncTask formAsyncTask = new FormListAsyncTask(this);
      formAsyncTask.execute("http://192.168.1.128/RestServiceImpl.svc/forms/");
    }

    private class FormListAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<String, Integer, List<Form>> {

        private Context mContext;
        private ProgressDialog loadingDialog;

        FormListAsyncTask(Context context)
        {
            mContext = context;
            loadingDialog = new ProgressDialog(mContext);
            loadingDialog.setProgressStyle(ProgressDialog.STYLE_HORIZONTAL);
            loadingDialog.setMessage("Downloading. Please wait...");
            loadingDialog.setCancelable(false);
            loadingDialog.setMax(100);
            loadingDialog.show();
        }

        @Override
        protected List<Form> doInBackground(String... url)
        {
            Log.v("doInBackground", "retreiving forms");
            return FormSpringController.LoadAll(url[0]);
        }
        // Just some example code to update your progress dialog
        protected void onProgressUpdate(Integer... values)
        {
            Log.v("onProgressUpdate", "updating: " + ((int) ((values[0] / (float) values[1]) * 100)));
            loadingDialog.setProgress((int) ((values[0] / (float) values[1]) * 100));
        }

        protected void onPostExecute(List<Form> forms)
        {
            if (forms != null)
            {
                ListActivity act = (ListActivity) mContext;
                act.setListAdapter(new FormAdapter(act, R.layout.form_list_item, forms));
                mForms = forms;
            }
            else
            {
                TextView errorMsg = (TextView)
                        ((FormsListActivity) mContext).findViewById(R.id.formErrorMsg);
                errorMsg.setText("Problem downloading forms. Please try again later.");
            }
            loadingDialog.dismiss();
        }
    }
}
```

Why loadingDialog's progress is not updated on onProgressUpdate?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am not finding any  `publishProgress();` in your code.

call publishProgress() from your `doInBackground()` which call override `onProgressUpdate()` implicitly.

Comment: I'm following this example: http://twigstechtips.blogspot.com.es/2011/11/for-my-app-moustachify-everything-i-was.html

Comment: try this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6450275/android-how-to-work-with-asynctasks-progressdialog