# only the original thread that created a view hierarchy can touch its views. android

Tags: android, multithreading, handler, progressdialog

```
public class master extends Activity {
    ProgressDialog    progressDialog;
    EditText tahmini_kelime;
    EditText girilen_sayi ;
    EditText toplam_harf_sayisi ;
    Button tamamdir; 
    TextView jTextArea1;
    Vector vector_all,vect_end,vect,recent_search;
    BufferedReader read;
    String recent_tahmin_kelime; 
    boolean bayrak,bayrak2 ;
    int column_number  ;
    InputStreamReader inputreader ;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
         requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
     setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);
           getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,
                    WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);

        setContentView(R.layout.master);
        column_number=0;
        bayrak=true;
          toplam_harf_sayisi=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.toplam_harf);
          tahmini_kelime=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.tahmini_kelime);
          girilen_sayi=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.sayi_gir);
          tamamdir=(Button)findViewById(R.id.tamamdirrrr);
            jTextArea1=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.jte);
            bayrak2=true;




            recent_search = new Vector();
            InputStream  inputStream =  getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.sozluk);
            try {
                  inputreader     = new InputStreamReader(inputStream,"utf-8");
            } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e1) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e1.printStackTrace();
            };
            read = new BufferedReader(inputreader);


            int k = 0;
            String result = "";
            try {

                vector_all = new Vector();
                while (read.ready()) {

                    result = read.readLine();
                    vector_all.add(result);
                    jTextArea1.append(result + "\n");
                    k = k + 1;
                }


                String size = "" + k;


            } catch (IOException ex) {
            }




          tamamdir.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {




                if( bayrak2 )
                {  
                    if(Integer.parseInt(toplam_harf_sayisi.getText().toString())>8 || Integer.parseInt(toplam_harf_sayisi.getText().toString())<=1)
                    { 
                            toplam_harf_sayisi.setText("");
                            Dialog  dl=new Dialog(master.this);
                            dl.setTitle("hatalı giriş");
                            dl.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(true);
                            dl.show(); 
                            return;
                    }


                     int findwordlength = Integer.parseInt(toplam_harf_sayisi.getText().toString());

                        int k = 0;
                        String result = "";
                        jTextArea1.setText("");
                        InputStream  inputStream =  getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.sozluk);
                        try {
                              inputreader     = new InputStreamReader(inputStream,"utf-8");
                        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e1) {
                            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                            e1.printStackTrace();
                        };
                        read = new BufferedReader(inputreader);

                        String resultword = "";
                        try {

                            vect = new Vector();



                             while (read.ready()) {

                                result = read.readLine();

                                if (result.length() == findwordlength) {

                                    vect.addElement(result);
                                    resultword = resultword + result + "\n";
                                    k = k + 1;
                                }
                                jTextArea1.setText("");
                            }



                            jTextArea1.append(resultword + "\n");

                            RandomKelime(vector_all,0 );



                        } catch (IOException ex) {
                        }

                        toplam_harf_sayisi.setEnabled(false);
                        girilen_sayi.setEnabled(true);
                        bayrak2=false;
                }
                else
                { 

                    progressDialog = ProgressDialog.show(master.this, "Bir Düşüneyim :D", "lütfen bekleyiniz...");
                    Thread thread = new Thread(new Runnable() {
                        public void run() {


                     mainGuessWord(column_number);


                     handler.sendEmptyMessage(0);
                        }
                    });
                    thread.start();  

                     girilen_sayi.setText("");

                         }



                        }




        });





    }

    private void mainGuessWord(int look) {
        int result_int = 0;
        String randomword = "";
        int randomword2 = 0;


        randomword = tahmini_kelime.getText().toString();


            result_int = Integer.parseInt(girilen_sayi.getText().toString());


        if (result_int == 0) {
            mevcut_degil(vect, randomword);
        } else {
            elemeAgaci(vect, randomword, result_int);
        }

    }


    public void elemeAgaci(Vector vect, String elem, int length) {
        String word = elem.toString();
        Vector cmp_vect;
        cmp_vect = new Vector();
        vect_end = new Vector();
        int count = 0;
        int countword = 0;  // toplam word sayısı
        int each_word_total = 0; // her kelimede bulunan harf sayısı
        jTextArea1.setText("");

            String compare = "";
            for (int i = 0; i < vect.size(); i++) {
                each_word_total = 0;
                compare = "";
                for (int j = 0; j < word.length(); j++) {

                    if(!compare.contains(""+word.charAt(j)))
                    {
                   for (int k = 0; k < vect.get(i).toString().length(); k++) {
                        if (vect.get(i).toString().charAt(k) == word.charAt(j)) {
                            each_word_total++;

                        }

                    }


                   compare=""+compare+word.charAt(j);
                    }

                }
                System.out.println("" + vect.get(i) + "  =>  " + each_word_total);

                if (length == each_word_total) {
                    cmp_vect.add(vect.get(i));
                    jTextArea1.append(vect.get(i) + "\n");
                    countword++;
                }

            }


            vect.clear();
            for (int l = 0; l < cmp_vect.size(); l++) {
                vect.add(cmp_vect.get(l));
            }




        if (countword == 1) {
                Dialog  dl=new Dialog(master.this);
                dl.setTitle("The Word id : "+jTextArea1.getText().toString());
                dl.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(true);
                dl.show(); 

        } else {
            column_number = column_number + 1;
            if(vect.size()<10){
            RandomKelime_Table(vect);
            }else{
            RandomKelime(vector_all, column_number);
            }
        }
    }

    public void mevcut_degil(Vector vect, String m) {
        char control[];
        control = m.toCharArray();
        boolean flag = false;
        int countword = 0;
        Vector detect;
        detect = new Vector();

        jTextArea1.setText("");
        for (int k = 0; k < vect.size(); k++) {
            flag = false;
            for (int s = 0; s < control.length; s++) {
                if (vect.get(k).toString().contains("" + control[s])) {
                    flag = true;
                }

            }
            if (!flag) {
                detect.addElement(vect.get(k));
                countword = countword + 1;
            }

        }
        vect.clear();
        for (int s = 0; s < detect.size(); s++) {
            vect.addElement(detect.get(s));
        }
        for (int a = 0; a < countword; a++) {
            jTextArea1.append(vect.get(a).toString() + "\n");
        }

        if (countword == 1) {
                Dialog  dl=new Dialog(master.this);
                dl.setTitle("The Word id : "+jTextArea1.getText().toString());
                dl.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(true);
                dl.show();
        } 

        else {
            column_number = column_number + 1;
            RandomKelime(vect, column_number);
        }
    }





    public void RandomKelime(Vector vector, int k)
    {
        String sesli[]={"a","e","ı","i","o","ö","u","ü"};

        Random a = new Random();

        if (k == 0) { 
            String passedword = "";
            passedword = vector_all.get((int) (Math.random() * vector_all.size())).toString();

            while (passedword.length() < 8) {
                passedword = vector_all.get((int) (Math.random() * vector_all.size())).toString();

            }

            tahmini_kelime.setText(passedword);
            recent_tahmin_kelime=passedword;

       // jTable1.setValueAt(vector_all.get((int) (Math.random() * vector_all.size())), k, 0);
        } else {
        recent_search.addElement(recent_tahmin_kelime );
        int say = 0;
        String design = "";
        String guess_words = "";
        String as="";
        int f=0;
        int count=0;
        int calculate_all=0;

        for (int u = 0; u < recent_search.size(); u++) {
        design = recent_search.get(u).toString();
        bayrak = false;
        as="";
        count=0;
        for(int  s=0;s<sesli.length;s++)
        {
        if(design.contains(""+sesli[s]) && count==0){
        as+=""+sesli[s];
        count++;
        }

        }

        guess_words = vector_all.get((int) a.nextInt(vector_all.size())).toString();

           while (guess_words.length() < 8) {
                guess_words = vector_all.get((int) (Math.random() * vector_all.size())).toString();

            }




        while (say < design.length()) {
          calculate_all=0;
        while (guess_words.contains("" + as) && !design.equals(guess_words)) {
        say = 0;
        calculate_all++;
        guess_words = vector_all.get( a.nextInt(vector_all.size())).toString();

          while (guess_words.length() < 8) {
                guess_words = vector_all.get((int) (Math.random() * vector_all.size())).toString();

            }



        f=f+1;
        System.out.println("Tahmın: " + guess_words + " => " + design);
        if(calculate_all>vect.size())
        {
        break;
        }
        }
        say++;
        System.out.println("coutn: " + say);
        }
        }


        if (true) {
        tahmini_kelime.setText(guess_words);
        }


        } 
    } 

     public void RandomKelime_Table(Vector vector ) {
            String passedword = "";
            Random a = new Random();

            try {


            passedword = vect.get(a.nextInt(vect.size())).toString();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                    Dialog  dl=new Dialog(master.this);
                    dl.setTitle("Hatalı Giriş.Yeniden Başlayın.");
                    dl.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(true);
                    dl.show(); 
                yeniden_basla();
            }
            tahmini_kelime.setText(passedword );

     }

     public void yeniden_basla()
     {  
         bayrak2=true;
         girilen_sayi.setEnabled(false);
         toplam_harf_sayisi.setEnabled(true);
         toplam_harf_sayisi.setText("");
         vect.clear();
         vector_all.clear();
         vect_end.clear();
         recent_search.clear();
         jTextArea1.setText("");
         recent_tahmin_kelime="";
         column_number=0;
         bayrak=true;
         InputStream  inputStream =  getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.sozluk);
            try {
                  inputreader     = new InputStreamReader(inputStream,"utf-8");
            } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e1) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e1.printStackTrace();
            };
            read = new BufferedReader(inputreader);


            int k = 0;
            String result = "";
            try {

                vector_all = new Vector();
                while (read.ready()) {

                    result = read.readLine();
                    vector_all.add(result);
                    jTextArea1.append(result + "\n");
                    k = k + 1;
                }


                String size = "" + k;


            } catch (IOException ex) {
            }
     }



     private Handler handler = new Handler() {
            @Override
            public void handleMessage(Message msg) {

                progressDialog.dismiss();


            }
        };  



}
```

this all of my code.

Comment: `girilen_sayi.setText("");` can not invoke in non-ui thread, you need do in the ui thread, or `handler.sendEmptyMessage(0);` when handle the message invoke `setText`

Comment: I use ui thread but it errors too

Comment: I delete girilen_sayi.setText(""); but it errors too

Comment: which line, can you paste the error logcat message, and `mainGuessWord` this method what it do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't show where you create your handler (onCreate ? onStart ? somewhere else ?). Is it started from the main thread ? If so, you need to be provide a more complete stack trace so we can understand.

If you're starting it from another thread then that's the issue because it's attempting to change progressDialog and that must be done from the main thread.

PS: if you used an AsyncTask you wouldn't have to scratch your head around this as it's designed to do exactly what you want and be thread safe.

*Post comment :* use an AsyncThread : add the progress bar in onPreExecute(), change run() to doInBackground() and move the dismiss() to onPostExecute(

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4538338/progressdialog-in-asynctask or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6450275/android-how-to-work-with-asynctasks-progressdialog if you want to show progress based on your word guessing progress

Comment: There are two links: one is showing progress based on your real progress and the other one does what you ask. Pick your favorite