# Android: show a progress dialog then dismiss properly

Tags: android, dialog

I've found that a lot of people are having a similar problem but I am simply trying to show a  dialog while I am grabbing some data off a URL and then dismiss properly after the data is  retrieved. Here is what I'm trying to do (This is in my onClick() method for a refresh button):

```
dialog.show();  
// do some work  
dialog.dismiss();
```

Doing it this way you never really see the dialog at all. I've tried doing it using an  extra thread such as:

```
Thread t = new Thread() {
    public void run() {
        dialog.show();
    }
};
```

But this way I get an error and a force close down...
**What is the best method to do this?**

Comment: check this http://codinglookseasy.blogspot.in/2012/10/save-image-in-sdcard.html here in the entire code there is a progress dialog in the onclick()

Comment: Use AsyncTask as it will be the best for this kind of task.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the task you are trying to implement:

```
dialog.show();  
// do some work  
dialog.dismiss();
```

Now, to implement above, there is concept of **[AsyncTask](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html)**, the best way to implement Threading task, as its also known as **Painless Threading in Android**.

AsyncTask has 4 main methods:

1. `onPreExecute()` - Here you can show ProgressDialog or ProgressBar.
2. `doInBackground()` - Here you can do/implement background task
3. `onProgressUpdate()` - Here you can update UI based on the intermediate result you receive from webservice call or from background task
4. `onPostExecute()` - Here you can dismiss dialog or make progress bar invisible. Also you can do the task which want to do after receiving result from background task or webservice call.

Comment: This is helpful thank you. I also just found someone who did this with a handler (see link) but it looks like what you have is more robust.  [link] http://www.helloandroid.com/tutorials/using-threads-and-progressdialog

Comment: @user1752041 yes thats also a solution, but why should we android developer need to bother about threading management if we already have something fantastic (i.e. AsyncTask)

Answer (score 0):

**For this kind of task mostly I recommend you to use the AsyncTask. [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6450275/android-how-to-work-with-asynctasks-progressdialog) is one good example of it which will help you.**

And for this question as You are making UI related task and for that please use the UI thread.

```
runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {

    @Override
    public void run() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    //Show or Hide your ProgressDialog
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to use runOnUiThread of the Activity instead of using Thread.
Check the following code snippet.
            runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {

```
            public void run() {

                    dialog = new ProgressDialog(ctContext);

                    dialog.show();
                }
            }

        });
```

I think this will help you.