# how to automatically increment a seekbar (without MediaPlayer)

Tags: android, seekbar

Is it possible to automatically increment  a seekbar every seconds for a specific duration ( Ex 60 mins) ??? ( i want to get something like a player progress bar , but i'm not using MediaPlayer)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

yes you can create custom progress same as seekbar and use Asynctask method to perfrom same operation. It means sleep for some time in doInbackground and update it in postexecute method.

Comment: can you tell me more , how can i do it ?

Comment: see this post,it will help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6450275/android-how-to-work-with-asynctasks-progressdialog