# Updating progress bar atomically/immediately after update in AsyncTask

Tags: java, android, android-asynctask

I have an `AsycTask` performing actions like copying or moving files in an app, and I update a progress bar in a dialog frequently with `publishProgress()`.

**PROBLEM**

The code works almost fine, though when the `AsyncTask` performs actions and updates the progress bar (calls `setProgress()` in `onProgressUpdate()`), it is not updated immediately, not until task is complete... yet the `TextView` updated at the same place is updated.

I tried a workaround... to use `sleep(1)` in the `AsyncTask` thread to allow the main thread to execute (update the progress bar :-) ). This worked and the progress bar got updated as the files were being deleted... but there is a big difference in excecution time as follows.

**Before adding** `sleep(1)`

---

Total files deleted - `3804`

Average time taken - `5s` (3 tests average)

**After adding** `sleep(1)`

---

Total files deleted - `3804`

Average time taken - `1m 40s` (3 tests average)

As you can see the `sleep(1)` caused a huge change in execution time. Is there another way around this... **To make progress bar update atomically**
I'm really greatful for any suggestions...here is the code...

> Note : I tried deleting the same files using another downloaded filemanager app that shows a progress bar during deletion and the time is relative to the test where i added the sleep(1) (1m 40s)

---

**My** `doInBackground()`

```java
@Override
protected Boolean doInBackground(HashMap.SimpleImmutableEntry<Integer, File[]>... args) {
  mTask = args [0].getKey ();
  mFiles = args [0].getValue ();

// This calls the method according to task
   
  switch (mTask) {
  case TASK_COPY:
      return copy ();

  case TASK_MOVE:
      return move ();
  ...
  }
}
```

---

**My** `onProgressUpdate()` (where i update the views, it is called frequently when i call `publishProgress()`)

```java
@Override
protected void onProgressUpdate (Object[] values) {
    ...
                    
    // THIS IS WHERE I UPDATE VALUES OF PROGRESS BAR IN PERCENTAGE
    // instance fields
    // private AtomicLong mProgress, mLimit
    
    double i = mProgress.get (), j = mLimit.get ();
    int k = ((int) (j < 1 ? 0 : (i / j) * 100));

    // THIS mTextView updates properly immediately
    mTextView.setText (mTaskMsg + k + "%\t\t" + mProgress.get () + "/" + mLimit.get ());
    
    // but this progress bar does update until task is fully done (that is to 100) unless i sleep(1)
    mProgressBar.setProgress (k, true);
}
```

---

**The other methods** called from the asynctask thread...

```java
// implemented FileVisitor

@Override
public FileVisitResult visitFile (Path path, BasicFileAttributes attrs) {
    mProgress.incrementAndGet ();
    publishProgress ();
            
    // THIS IS WHERE I AM FORCED TO SLEEP TO ALLOW PROGRESS UPDATE IN MAIN THREAD
       
    try {
        Thread.sleep(1); // NOT REALLY THE BEST I KNOW...
        Files.delete (path); }
    catch (Throwable t) {
        publishProgress (ERROR_CODE, t); }
    return FileVisitResult.CONTINUE;
}
@Override
public FileVisitResult visitFileFailed (Path path, IOException io) {
     mProgress.incrementAndGet ();
     publishProgress (ERROR_CODE, io);
     return FileVisitResult.CONTINUE;
}
@Override
public FileVisitResult postVisitDirectory (Path path, IOException io) {
     mProgress.incrementAndGet ();
     publishProgress ();

     try {
         Files.delete (path); }
     catch (Throwable t) {
         publishProgress (ERROR_CODE, t); }
    return FileVisitResult.CONTINUE;
}

...

private boolean delete () {
    publishProgress ();
    try {
        if (mFiles [0].isDirectory ()) {
            Stream<Path> s = Files.walk (mFiles [0].toPath ());
                    
        // I count the files here myself because the count method
        // of the stream crashes if files are 3000+ the app with no exception...i caught Throwable.
        // Though its not the issue...
            s.forEach (this);
            publishProgress ();

            Files.walkFileTree (mFiles [0].toPath (), this);
            }
            else {
                 mLimit.incrementAndGet ();
                 mProgress.incrementAndGet ();
                 publishProgress ();

                 return mFiles [0].delete ();
            }
     }
     catch (Throwable t) {
          publishProgress (ERROR_CODE, t); }
    return false;
}
```

---