# ProggressDialog wont show in asynctask

Tags: android, android-asynctask, progressdialog

My code will grab jsonString from web in AsyncTask, and then return this string (auth2) back to MainActivity.

I have problem that progressDialog wont show in AsyncTask.

My AsyncTask code:

```
    /**
 * Async task class to get json by making HTTP call
 * */
private class GetContacts extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
        // Showing progress dialog
        pDialog = new ProgressDialog(MyActivity.this);
        pDialog.setMessage("Please wait...");
        pDialog.setCancelable(false);
        pDialog.show();

    }

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
        // Creating service handler class instance
        ServiceHandler sh = new ServiceHandler();
        //pass url string
        String url = params[0];
        // Making a request to url and getting response
        String jsonStr = sh.makeServiceCall(url, ServiceHandler.POST);
        if (jsonStr != null) {
            try {
                JSONObject jsonObj = new JSONObject(jsonStr);
                JSONObject jsonUserInfo=jsonObj.getJSONObject("user_info");
                String auth2 = jsonUserInfo.getString("auth");
                return auth2;

            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        } else {
            Log.e("ServiceHandler", "Couldn't get any data from the url");
        }
        return null;

    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String auth2) {
        super.onPostExecute(auth2);
        // Dismiss the progress dialog
        if (pDialog.isShowing()){
            pDialog.dismiss();
        }

    }

}
```

What could be problem? Is it related to methods void,string etc?

Comment: why you call super.onPreExecute?

Comment: How do you calling 'GetContacts' AsyncTask

Comment: I pass host with apiHost  , and call is made with try like this: String auth2 = new GetContacts().execute(apiHost).get();

Comment: `get()` will block the UI, so try like this `new GetContacts().execute(apiHost)`

Answer (score -1):

`onProgressUpdate()` is used to update progress on UI. It takes one parameter that corresponds to the second parameter in the `AsyncTask` class definition. This callback can be triggered from within the body of the `doInBackground()` method by calling `publishProgress()`.

For more information, check [this](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html) link and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6450275/android-how-to-work-with-asynctasks-progressdialog) link.