# Android Studio - Make an activity wait until loading UI

Tags: java, android

I have an activity which contains a `recyclerView` that loads data from the database. Sometimes when starting the activity I don't see the data until reloading the activity.

What I'm trying to do is show a loading animation for 3 seconds and wait for it to load then show it.

I added this to my xml:

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/loadingPanel"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:gravity="center" >

    <ProgressBar
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:indeterminate="true" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

But how can I make my activity wait for 3 seconds (showing the loading animation) and then go back to the activity with loaded data?

Comment: use callbacks or events, pausing main thread or implementing fix delay is code smell

Comment: can u explain a bit more, the question is not clear

Comment: I don't think you should wait for exactly 3 seconds. If you are loading your Recyclerview data from an API it may take less/more time than that depending on your network speed, server, etc. The best way is to cancel your progress dialog once you load your data through a call back. Could u share the code where u r loading the data

Comment: Are you aiming to wait AT LEAST 3 seconds or more if needed. Or would you expect that the load will be always less than 3 seconds. Otherwise, @ other commenters: sometimes it is worth setting minimum loading indicator time so that you do not frustrate the user.

Comment: When I start my activity, my recyclerView is empty, now I want to make my activity wait until my recyclerView has the data from the database, but while it's waiting I want to show loading animation.

Comment: you can use an asyncTask: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6450275/android-how-to-work-with-asynctasks-progressdialog

Answer (score 0):

1. Create a callback class:

   `interface Callback {
       public void onStart();
       public void onComplete(<your_data_type> data);
    }`
2. Add a callback as an argument to your method, that loads data from database, then you need to call the callback's methods when the events happen:

   `public void loadData(Callback callback) {
       callback.onStart();
       <your_data_type> data = /* load data from database */;
       callback.onComplete(data);
    }`
3. Pass it an implemented callback to loadData method:

   `loadData(new Callback {
       public void onStart() {
           // start showing your progress bar
       }
       public void onComplete(<your_data_type> data) {
           // show data in your recycler view
           // hide your progress bar
       }`
   });

And of course you need to call `loadData()` method in a background thread and call the callback's methods in a main thread.